# BCP utility corrupts data

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, bcp

I am running a bulk copy of two columns of a table from one server to another.

The table on the source side has about 8 columns, but I only need 2.

The table on the destination side has 2 columns (the two that I need, both are of type int)

Both databases are SQL Server 2005.

Here's my two bcp commands:

```
c:\> bcp "select c1, c2 from srcTable" queryout tableData.bcp -N -T -S srcServer
c:\> bcp destTable in tableData.bcp -N -T -S destServer
```

Why does this corrupt the data in the destination table?  I should be getting nice, sequential integers, instead I get this:

```
c1          c2
586332      83014148
123128736   -105042384
-561616278  -309997736
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

The column definition must match exactly - **including whether it is NULL or NOT NULL.**

The source had:

```
srcTable (
c1 int not null (PK)
c2 int null
c3 datetime not null
c4 datetime null
...
)
```

The destination table had:

```
destTable (
c1 int not null (PK)
c2 int not null 
)
```

The NOT NULL on destTable.c2 was the bug.

It's been squashed now.